# predefined type System.Range is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I'm using C# 8.0 (beta) in my UWP app with Visual Studio 2019 v16.0.2.
I was trying to use the new range operator of C# 8 : `str[start..index]` and then two errors showed up:

> Predefined type `System.Range` is not defined or imported

> Predefined type `System.Index` is not defined or imported

But there is no such reference that I could use.

Visual Studio itself suggested me to use this feature. Is that the feature hasn't made available yet or what?

Comment: C# 8 and the .NET Core 3 runtime on which it depends are in Preview, not even beta. Which .NET Core 3 SDK version have you installed? You may have to install a newer version.

Comment: it still does that for .net framework 4.8.1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a part of .NET Core 3 which is not released yet.

Comment: Wonderful, I googled "C# range array" and one of the first results was https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes with absolutely NO indication that this is not even released yet, just reads like a normal tutorial about pretty basic stuff...

Answer (score 20):

Indices and Ranges is a part of C# 8.0, which was released together with .NET Core 3.0 in September 2019. To use all of the C# 8.0 features, your *target framework* must be one of the following:

- .NET Standard 2.1
- .NET Core 3.0 and later
- .NET 5.0 and later

It is also possible to use C# 8.0 features on earlier versions of .NET, such as .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework. To do this you need to [override the default C# version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) on your project. However, Indices and Ranges is not officially supported on these earlier versions and will not work out-of-the-box. That being said, there is a possible workaround to make it work: https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-use-csharp-8-indices-and-ranges-in-dotnet-standard-2-0-and-dotn.htm